# Unable to load main.storyboard

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am using Xamarin Studio 6.1.2-Build 44 (on my Mac Sierra 10.12.1) and am currently subscribed to the beta channel (although I did start with the stable one).  When attempting to view the main.storyboard it just spins for a while and then ultimately dies after a few minutes with "The designer could not be initialized" and the errors below.
Note that the actual log is far far longer but I'm not sure what's relevant at this point.  I've seen [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41208617/cant-open-xamarin-ios-designer-visual-studio-2017) reports of this error but have been unable to resolve the issue through the means I've seen posted.

Note that I've updated the error message below after much review of the logs.  This appears to be the root cause although I will continue to dig.

```
[2016-12-19 19:51:43.3] INFO: Waiting for server to spin up... 300
```

Also [there is a bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=34734) but no real answer provided yet.

Comment: What version of XCode of you have? Please make sure t hat is updated as well.